# How to play video stored on a online file server?

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview, android-video-player

I have to play a video in my android app. The file is stored on a online file server

link is : http://view.vzaar.com/923037/video

I am unable to play this file using VideoView. I also tried to load this file into WebView but the WebView opens Web Browser and then the file starts playing.

Is there any way to play these kind of file directly into my app without downloading into device?

Comment: Provided this is an MP4 file (which it seems like it is), you should be able to play it in VideoView.  Show us your code, maybe we'll spot the problem then.

Comment: VideoView mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vdoTest);
mVideoView.setVideoPath("http://view.vzaar.com/923037/video");
mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));

This is my code for VideoView

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your VideoView, the prpoblem is with `setVideoPath` method.  You need to use `setVideoURI` instead to specify a streaming source:

```
VideoView mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vdoTest);
mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
String viewSource ="http://view.vzaar.com/923037/video";
mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(viewSource));
```

This should work, provided the video is encoded correctly: (AAC+H.264, baseline)

Comment: Thanks a lot Aleks. You solved my problem. Work like a charm.

Just one more question, Can I show thumbnail of video?

Thnx in advance

Answer (score 1):

write this html code and load it in webview:

```
<html><body><embed src="http://view.vzaar.com/923037/video" width="100%" height="100%"></embed></body></html>
```

Comment: Sorry sir I have tried your method but it dosent work.
Only a blank page show. but thnx for your help.